# i have two tables and wanna use join query but while creating second table i got an error of - foreign key constraints is incorrectly formed

Tags: mysql

**1st Table**

```sql
create table if not exists Employee (
id int not null auto_increment,
name varchar (55) default null,
dept_id int default null,
birth text default null,
primary key (`id`)
);
```

**2nd Table**

```sql
create table if not exists dept_name (
dep_id int not null,
dept_name varchar(55) default null,
dept_block varchar(55) default null,
constraint pk_dept primary key(dep_id),
constraint EMP_employee foreign key(dep_id) references Employee(dept_id)
);
```

I am creating the second table to try a join query using the foreign key.

Comment: below query is not working  - select `name`,`birth`,`dept_name`,`dept_block`
from `dept_name`
join `Employee` using (`dep_id`);

Answer (score 0):

You have your foreign key in the wrong "direction". A foreign key should always reference a unique value in the target (e.g., a primary key).

The department ID is unique in the department table, not the employee table. In short - create the `dept_name` table first, and then create the employee table with teh foreign key referencing it:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS dept_name (
    dep_id INT NOT NULL, 
    dept_name VARCHAR(55) DEFAULT NULL,
    dept_block VARCHAR(55) DEFAULT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT pk_dept PRIMARY KEY(dep_id)
    -- No foreign key here
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Employee (
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name VARCHAR(55) DEFAULT NULL,
    dept_id INT DEFAULT NULL,
    birth TEXT DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    CONSTRAINT EMP_employee foreign key(dept_id) REFERENCES dept_name(dep_id)
);
```

Comment: thanks for the help, but after doing changes as directed above, i am trying to run below query but is shows error,select `name`,`birth`,`dept_name`,`dept_block`
from `dept_name`
join `Employee` using (`dep_id`);

Comment: @ViralDoshi for a natural join both columns should have the same name, but here you have `dep_id` and `dept_id`. Either rename one them so they both have the same name, or use an explicit join: `JOIN Employee on Employee.dept_id = dept_name.dep_id`.